# Counting the solutions of a quadratic equation

Tags: finite-fields, quadratics

I have read that a non-singular conic will contain $p+1$ points on the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, but there is a exercise on Silverman's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, p.142, 4.8 that tells us that if $p\equiv3\pmod 4$ is a prime and $b\in\mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$, the equation $v^2=u^4–4d$ has $p-1$ points in $\mathbb{F}_{p}\times\mathbb{F}_{p}$. But $u^2\mapsto u^4$ is an automorphism in the group of quadratic residues. So it should contain exactly same number of points with the conic case. So where are the missing two points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing points are on the line at infinity.

The statement that the number of $\Bbb{F}_p$-rational points on a non-singular conic is $p+1$ applies to projective plane curves. This exercise is about the number of points on the affine plane $(u,v)\in\Bbb{F}_p^2$.

Notice that the corresponding quadratic curve
$$
v^2=u^2-4d
$$
has two points on the line at infinity. Namely the ideal points of the two lines $v=\pm u$. Or, if you prefer projective coordinates of the curve
$$
V^2=U^2-4dW^2,
$$
then those two points have homogeneous coordinates
$$[U:V:W]=[1:\pm1:0].$$

Comment: Oh, I see. This is a silly question.

Comment: Not silly at all, @IntoksLiobein. It takes a while to get used to the difference between the affine and projective variants of curves (and higher dimensional varieties). Such bookkeeping is taxing at times. I have done mistakes like double counting some points due to this myself. Once you become aware of the peril you, of course, quickly learn to double check :-)